# Magento: How to resize image in view?

Tags: magento, image-resizing

I've got this (common) code in my product view:

```
$this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'image');
```

If I add `->resize(265)` the new image does not resize.. and no image is loaded at its place (error 404).
How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change media/catalog directory permission to 0755 of magento